# Problems with ng-model in a select tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a select element and i try to retriev the value selected using ng-model. It is displayed on my application page correctly but in the app controller it's still on the initial value. I've been looking for answers an the net but i don't find anything satisfying.

my select :

```
<select  ng-model= "choice.selected" ng-init = "choice.selected = historicOptions[0].id" ng-options = "historicOption.id as historicOption.value for historicOption in historicOptions">            
</select>
<br> choice : {{choice.selected}}
```

The options and the variable used to get the value selected (initiated to a default value):

```
$scope.historicOptions = [
    {id: 0, value: "month"},
    {id: 1, value: "week"},
    {id: 2, value: "day"}
  ];
$scope.choice ={selected: 0};
```

**EDIT**

Here is my angular application (where i do console.log())

```
var app =  angular.module('AppEfergy', []);

app.factory('historicFactory',[function(){
  var h = {
    historic: []
  };

  h.createHistoric = function(choix){
    console.log("choix = ", choix);
     if(choix == 0){
     return h.historic = [
    {date:"October"   ,consumption:230},
    {date:"September" ,consumption:235},
    {date:"August"    ,consumption:235},
    {date:"July"      ,consumption:240}
    ];
  }
   else if(choix == 1){
     return h.historic = [
    {date:"28/09/2015 - 04/10/2015" ,consumption:52},
    {date:"05/10/2015 - 11/10/2015" ,consumption:55},
    {date:"12/10/2015 - 18/10/2015" ,consumption:48},
    {date:"19/10/2015 - 25/10/2015" ,consumption:50},
    {date:"26/10/2015 - 01/11/2015" ,consumption:49}
    ];
  }
   else if(choix == 2){
     return h.historic = [
    {date:"01/11/2015" ,consumption:10},
    {date:"31/10/2015" ,consumption:11},
    {date:"30/10/2015" ,consumption:9 },
    {date:"29/10/2015" ,consumption:8 },
    {date:"28/10/2015" ,consumption:8 },
    {date:"27/10/2015" ,consumption:10},
    {date:"26/10/2015" ,consumption:9 }

    ];
  }

  };
  return h;
}]);


app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope','historicFactory', function($scope, historicFactory){
  $scope.choice ={selected: 0};
  $scope.choiceBis ={selected: 0};

  $scope.historicOptions = [
    {id: 0, value: "month"},
    {id: 1, value: "week"},
    {id: 2, value: "day"}
  ];

  $scope.saveOptions = [
    {id: 0, value: -10},
    {id: 1, value: -5 },
    {id: 2, value: 5  },
    {id: 3, value: 10 } 
  ];

  $scope.currentValue = 237;
  $scope.cost = 21;
  $scope.saving = 3;

     $scope.historic = historicFactory.createHistoric($scope.choice.selected); 
  console.log("choice : ", $scope.choice.selected);


}]);
```

and my html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Efergy App</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href ="EfergyStyle.css">

    <!-- include Angular library-->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js"></script>

        <!-- include the AngularApp-->
    <script src="AppEfergy.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app = "AppEfergy", ng-controller = "MainCtrl">
    <header>
      Power Consumption
    </header> 
    <div class = "currentConsumption">
      <br><h2>Current Consumption</h2>
      <span class = "Value" ng-bind = "currentValue"></span>
      <span class="unit">kW</span>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div class = "historic">

      <h3>Historic</h3>
      Display an historic by 
      <select  ng-model= "choice.selected" ng-options = "historicOption.id as historicOption.value for historicOption in historicOptions">

      </select>
      <br> choice : {{choice.selected}}
     <br> 

      <table class = "historic">
        <tr>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Average consumption (kW)</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat = "historics in historic">
          <td>
            {{historics.date}}
          </td>
          <td>
            {{historics.consumption}}
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it correct? http://jsfiddle.net/crndngdc/

Comment: It seems working code and correct code

Comment: It works but when i do consol.log(choice) it always print 0 even when I select another option

Comment: Where do you console.log()? Put the code here.

Comment: @ParthaSarathiGhosh I edited my post, I put the angular and the html code, if it can help you understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following code on your controller

```
$scope.getSelectedValue = function() {
  console.log("choice : ", $scope.choice.selected);
  $scope.historic = historicFactory.createHistoric($scope.choice.selected);
};
```

Add this event to your select as follows

```
ng-change="getSelectedValue()"
```

In your code you did not call a method on change of your select. That is why you get 0 as console pint for first time controller initialization.

Check the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/jPBnvn6FJVHXhdEQT3QO

Comment: A deferred call ? I don't understand. my select is in an html fil and my historicOptions is in a js file (my angular appliation) so if I'm right the app does its stuff when it is asked to in the html file. not sur if i'm clear :/

Answer (score 0):

You are using ng-options which is a preferred choice when you want to retrieve the selected model, but not a string value. You example shows that you are just expecting the index of the selected item.

Here is the code that should work fine:

```
<select  ng-model= "selected" 
 ng-options = "historicOption as historicOption.value for historicOption in    historicOptions"></select>
     <br> choice : {{selected.value}}
```

Here is the Controller:

```
 $scope.historicOptions = [
    {id: 0, value: "month"},
    {id: 1, value: "week"},
    {id: 2, value: "day"}
 ];
 $scope.selected =$scope.historicOptions[0];
```

Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/FVaxzX7reeqS4jiSacNp?p=preview)

**Update:**
Now if you just want the id to be used as the value for the option and the value as the label, you simply use `select` with `ng-repeat`.

```
<select ng-model="selected">
    <option ng-repeat="option in historicOptions" 
   value="{{option.id}}">{{option.value}}</option>
</select>
<br> choice : {{selected}}

$scope.historicOptions = [
    {id: 0, value: "month"},
    {id: 1, value: "week"},
    {id: 2, value: "day"}
  ];
$scope.selected =0;
```

Comment: That's it, I want to get the id because i want to diplay a table depending on this id, the value is just a label, but the selected is well displayed on the html page but stay at 0 in the angular code so it always display the same table

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `ng-init = "choice.selected = historicOptions[0].id"` because this will always show you zero indexed value. so remove this and try to use this code below, if you want to dropdown selected value then you have to add ng-change directive.

Your Code look like this

```js
var app = angular.module('AppEfergy', []);

app.factory('historicFactory', [
  function() {
    var h = {
      historic: []
    };
    h.createHistoric = function(choix) {
      console.log("choix = ", choix);
      if (choix == 0) {
        return h.historic = [{
          date: "October",
          consumption: 230
        }, {
          date: "September",
          consumption: 235
        }, {
          date: "August",
          consumption: 235
        }, {
          date: "July",
          consumption: 240
        }];
      } else if (choix == 1) {
        return h.historic = [{
          date: "28/09/2015 - 04/10/2015",
          consumption: 52
        }, {
          date: "05/10/2015 - 11/10/2015",
          consumption: 55
        }, {
          date: "12/10/2015 - 18/10/2015",
          consumption: 48
        }, {
          date: "19/10/2015 - 25/10/2015",
          consumption: 50
        }, {
          date: "26/10/2015 - 01/11/2015",
          consumption: 49
        }];
      } else if (choix == 2) {
        return h.historic = [{
          date: "01/11/2015",
          consumption: 10
        }, {
          date: "31/10/2015",
          consumption: 11
        }, {
          date: "30/10/2015",
          consumption: 9
        }, {
          date: "29/10/2015",
          consumption: 8
        }, {
          date: "28/10/2015",
          consumption: 8
        }, {
          date: "27/10/2015",
          consumption: 10
        }, {
          date: "26/10/2015",
          consumption: 9
        }];
      }
    };
    return h;
  }
]);


app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'historicFactory',
  function($scope, historicFactory) {

    $scope.choice = {
      selected: 0
    };
    $scope.choiceBis = {
      selected: 0
    };

    $scope.historicOptions = [{
      id: 0,
      value: "month"
    }, {
      id: 1,
      value: "week"
    }, {
      id: 2,
      value: "day"
    }];

    $scope.saveOptions = [{
      id: 0,
      value: -10
    }, {
      id: 1,
      value: -5
    }, {
      id: 2,
      value: 5
    }, {
      id: 3,
      value: 10
    }];

    $scope.getSelectedValue = function() {
      console.log("choice : ", $scope.choice.selected);
      $scope.historic = historicFactory.createHistoric($scope.choice.selected);
    };

    $scope.currentValue = 237;
    $scope.cost = 21;
    $scope.saving = 3;

    $scope.historic = historicFactory.createHistoric($scope.choice.selected);
    console.log("choice : ", $scope.choice.selected);
  }
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Efergy App</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="EfergyStyle.css">

  <!-- include Angular library-->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js"></script>

  <!-- include the AngularApp-->
  <script src="AppEfergy.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="AppEfergy" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <header>
    Power Consumption
  </header>
  <div class="currentConsumption">
    <br>
    <h2>Current Consumption</h2>
    <span class="Value" ng-bind="currentValue"></span>
    <span class="unit">kW</span>
  </div>
  <br>

  <div class="historic">

    <h3>Historic</h3>
    Display an historic by
    <select data-ng-model="choice.selected" data-ng-change="getSelectedValue()" data-ng-options="historicOption.id as historicOption.value for historicOption in historicOptions">
    </select>
    <br>choice : {{choice.selected}}
    <br>
    <table class="historic">
      <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Average consumption (kW)</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="historics in historic">
        <td>{{historics.date}}
        </td>
        <td>{{historics.consumption}}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it doesn't seems to fix my problem, i did a console.log($scope.choice.selected) in the angular code and it doesn't get the value of the option i choose

Comment: Ok let me see your problem. I will fix this as soon as possible.

Comment: your application is right. you just print one time so console value is 0 for the first time, if you $scope.choice = { selected: 1 }; then console value will be 1. Thanks.

Comment: Oh ! ok, but if i get the right id, why my factory doesn't display the right table ? It seems that no matter the value of the id it will always display first the table ( when choix = 0 )

Answer (score 0):

I presume this is part of a larger solution (i.e. that its not just one select box and value). Your template might be structured so that it starts a new child scope.

This means that your initial `$scope.choice = { selected: 0 };` does not do anything to actually set the selected values for your pulldown (to confirm this, try changing selected to 1). Instead the pulldown values are simply set by virtue of 0 being the first entry.

When you change the pulldown value you are simply creating the property in the (prototypically inherited) child scope (and not doing anything to the now masked choice property in the parent scope).

The easiest way to fix this would be to refer to the choice property in the parent scope (use $parent.choice) - whether or not this is the right fit depends on the rest of your code.

Here is one template illustrating the problem

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/0un8p2dh/